# How to Shrink Blue Outline on Page So Everything Shows on Screen

Tags: column

Please forgive me, but I do not know code at all, and I have been asked to maintain our teacher SharePoint page.  Yay! Would you take a look at this screenshot?
I've obviously done something wrong.  I want three columns of images.  Each image (except the slideshow) has a link you can click on.  I notice there is a blue line and the black line--where I tried to insert a table on top in the hopes of fixing the problem.  How can I move the blue line over so that all three columns show on the screen at the same time?  Again, forgive my ineptitude, and keep it in mind as you answer!   Michelle
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally when designing web interfaces it is *definitely not* best practice to format your page using tables, however from my experience SharePoint Pages tend to be structured in such a way that often using tables is the preferred method of structuring your page layout.

In your case I would recommend inserting a new table of a single row and three columns and inserting each image into a separate cell in the table. To do this, first insert a table.

[image]

Then select each cell individually to insert an image. You can link to an image directly in SharePoint (recommended) or upload directly from your computer

[image]

If you wish to add a link to the image just select the cell or image and use the "insert link" but leave the 'text' field blank. A tutorial video is available here: https://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SPLinksImage.htm

Now the layout should be correct but the table should have a black border, so to remove the black border you need to set the table design to clear:

[image]

That should achieve the result you're looking for, however if it does not you may have to change your page layout under the format text menu:

[image]

I'm unsure what you mean by the blue border, but if you have made the image a hyperlink it will be highlighted with a blue border by default when selected. This is due to the CSS feature ":focus" explained by W3 schools here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

To change that you would have to use the INSERT>EMBED CODE, with which you can inject custom CSS using  tags. BEar in mind, however, that due to a bug in SharePoint pages you must first save your custom code with  tags and save the page, then edit the web part and change them to  tags, otherwise the script editor web part will lose all your code and just go blank (I lost days and lot's of hair due to this bug).

Edit: Looking closely at your screenshot it seems you are attempting to place multiple images in a single cell and the blue border is the table outline. To achieve this effect, I would place a 1X1 table (Table A) and insert a nested 1X3 table (Table B) *inside* the single cell table. Then Table A can be styled to have a Blue Outline and Table B can have a clear outline.